# How can I convert extremely large json files (150GB +) that have line lengths greater than 2GB?

Tags: json, jq

Every month I receive extremely large and complex json files. The files are routinely 1-50GB and sometimes larger than 150GB. The files are loaded into aws emr hive tables, then processed using hive json functions.
When the process attempts to load a json file that contains a line with a length greater than 2GB the process fails.

I tried using jq (jq -c . < source.json > output.json ) to compact and format the files. This worked on smaller test files but does not scale. I tried jq's stream function but the process used up memory when rebuilding the structure.

I am looking for a way to reformat a json file, that has line lengths exceeding 2GB, that does not require loading the entire file into memory.

Can this be accomplished with jq?

[50GB test file] (https://webtpa-public-access.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/subfolder/2023_06_430_65B0_in_network_rates.json.gz)

Comment: JSON files should never be that large - have you complained to your upstream provider (i.e. whoever is giving you 150GB-sized JSON files) and told them to use a more appropriate format (ideally, an indexable and structured binary format that doesn't require full-parsing)? If so, what was the excuse they gave?

Comment: _"When the process attempts to load a json file that contains a line with a length greater than 2GB the process fails."_ - just to clarify, is this a file comprised of self-contained JSON objects one-per-line? If so, then that isn't a JSON file, it's [a "JSON Lines" file](https://jsonlines.org/). (And if every line/record in a JSON Lines file has the exact same JSON object structure then methinks that data _should_ be better-represented using CSV or a portable database file like a Sqlite DB, methinks.

Comment: @Dai some early files are close to 1 TB. These are insurance price transparency files and are generated only for payers to be compliant. One hurdle is that each may or may not provide the full structure. The 'standard' is located [here](https://github.com/CMSgov/price-transparency-guide/tree/master/schemas/in-network-rates)

Comment: TIL that JSON-Lines and NDJSON are competing: https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson.github.io/issues/1

Comment: @dai I updated my question to remove NDJSON as jq -c . format works but doesn't scale. I simply need to remove/handle the 2GB line issue. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd probably write a (compiled) program that uses the OS-provided file IO functions to efficiently rebuild the file by scanning for long-lines without needing to buffer or parse the entire file into memory, perhaps using low-level filesystem extents to avoid copying (as opposed to using shell utilities like `jq`,`sed` or `awk`) - but I don't know if that's something you'd do or not.

Comment: Perhaps just appending a newline whenever a sufficiently common key-value pair is found would suffice? eg. `gawk -v RS='"plan_market_type": "(group|individual)",' 'ORS=RT"\n"' <infile >outfile`

Comment: @dai Yes, that is the next step and I have started looking at simdjson (don't know how steep c++ learning curve is). -jhnc  I tried using gawk with 50GB file on laptop but process was killed. Will attempt on server shortly.

Comment: simdjson will only help you if your bottleneck is in-memory processing - but if you've got a huge JSON blob like that then your bottleneck will be disk IO - simply reading through 160GB is going to take probably dozens of minutes.

Comment: @TheCrusher did you set RS like I demonstrated? If not, gawk will read until newline. You need to set a regex for RS that occurs often enough to be useful to you.

Comment: This is a job for a tool with an event-driven model. Those are a lot harder to use than object-model tools, but them's the breaks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you elaborate on that? When people speak-of event-driven models (Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc) I think of firehose streams of data from things like IoT sensors and $-expensive social-media stream APIs - but here the OP doesn't have a constant stream, but instead a data-dump once-a-month, so I'm curious how you'd suggest an archtectural migration to handle that (or did I completely misunderstand your comment?)

Comment: @Dai I mean the kind of parser where you get a callback for every token. SAX is the canonical example in the XML-parsing world, but folks have built them for JSON too. Feed your big data dump in, get millions of callbacks into a set of functions you provide -- a "here's a new object being started" callback, a "starting a new key in a map" callback, a "here's a list being opened" callback, a "here's a list being closed" callback, etc etc etc.

Comment: @Dai, incidentally, that's how jq works in `--stream` mode, so it can be used to convert between the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that JSON can only contain escaped double-quotes inside double-quoted strings. This leads me to believe it is safe to append newlines after something of form `"`**key**`":"`**value**`"`.

If you can choose a key/value pair that occurs sufficiently often, then you can use gawk to insert newlines.

Taking an example from your "standard" that seems to appear quite often in your test file:

```
gawk -v RS='"negotiation_arrangement":"(ffs|bundle|capitation)"' \
     'ORS=RT"\n"' <infile >outfile
```

inserts a newline after every occurrence of this regex.

gawk read records one at a time, delimited by the regex in `RS`, and sets `ORS` to be the actual string (`RT`) followed by newline. Since the `ORS` assignment result is always "truthy", the default print action occurs.

Memory usage will be some small multiple of the maximum length between occurrences of the regex.

For the test file provided, my 5-year old laptop took half an hour to run `zcat | gawk | wc -l` while I was using the machine for other things, needed <44MB virtual memory, was CPU-bound, and finally reported 333443 lines. `zcat | wc -c` took 5 minutes.

Comment: when running the above against a 50GB file (added link to test file in question) changing the key/value pair to "in_network":"negotiated_rates" resulted in running out of memory (8c 64GB aws linux box).

Comment: error msg: gawk: fatal: grow_iop_buffer: iop->buf: can't allocate 68719476738 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)

Comment: you need to use something that actually exists in the file!

Comment: Ideally the new line would be after the negotiated_rates array of objects which consists of three arrays of objects which each containing arrays/objects. I understand your example but how can a nested array of objects be represented here? I've tried: gawk -v RS='"negotiated_rates":"(negotiated_prices)"' \ 'ORS=RT"\n"'  <infile >outfile on a 2.5GB test file, but it has been running for a while.

Comment: I understood the problem to be simply to make sure the line length was <2GB. Are you trying to solve some different problem from that stated in the question?

Comment: It doesn't look like your test file contains the string `"negotiated_rates":"negotiated_prices"` so your regex will never match and the entire file will get loaded as a single record (or gawk will crash)

Comment: thank you, you have answered the asked question which now allows me to work on the next issue. And the test file does contain ""negotiated_rates":[{"negotiated_prices":[{"negotiated_rate":157.50,", which can be viewed in the tail, but you're correct in that my parameters don't match the data causing the gawk crash.